# Firebase não funciona com múltiplos aplicativos

Tags: android, firebase

tudo bem?

Iniciei um projeto no Firebase e linkei dois aplicativos relacionados no mesmo projeto.

Fiz um sistema de login/signin igual para ambos. Acontece que para um aplicativo, o sign in funciona normal mas para o segundo aplicativo, quando clico registrar o app nunca completa a resposta. O método para o sign in é igual nos dois:

```
 public void bntRegistrarRClick(View v)
    {
        (firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(txtEmail.getText().toString(), txtSenha.getText().toString())).
                addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if(task.isSuccessful())
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(RegistroActivity.this, "Registrado com Sucesso", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            Intent i = new Intent(RegistroActivity.this, CreateProfileActivity.class);
                            startActivity(i);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Log.e("ERROR", task.getException().toString());
                            Toast.makeText(RegistroActivity.this, task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                });

    }
```

Alguém faz ideia do porquê do problema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

agradeço o comentário, talvez não tenha me explicado muito bem! O que queria era que dois aplicativos se conectassem no mesmo banco o que não estava conseguindo fazer.

O problema era que eu tinha colocado os aplicativos em projetos diferentes do Android Studio e na verdade eles deveriam estar no mesmo projeto com módulos diferentes.

Answer (score 0):

Vai no painel do firebase -> Autenticação ->Metodos de login -> Várias contas por endereço de e-mail é habilite a opção assim o mesmo email pode logar varias vezes. Acompanhe na area usuarios para ver o resultado.